# Saving image in static/media folder via django admin issue

Tags: django, model, admin

Please tell why when I save image via admin I can not see it? Image saves in database but I can not see it if just press link with saved image in admin panel. I get Page not found (404) because there is no image file in this path but if I insert file in folder in my project with the same path,I can see it. Thus, Static files path is defined properly.
I have image field in model:

```
 photo = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'photo/', blank=True)`
```

settings:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static")
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
)
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '..', 'static','media')
MEDIA_URL = '/static/media/'
```

and seems it should save it in my project static folder but it does not .

my project structure:

```
project/
       -app/
    -static/
           --media/
                  ---photo/
```

Comment: Did you set `MEDIA_ROOT` path? User-upload files usually saved in /media/ directory, not /static/

Comment: yes, MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '..', 'static','media')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Media root should be like this -

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static','media')
```

Ensure the following things - There exists a folder named 'static' in the folder where your project exists. It should contain a folder named 'media'.

UPDATE: I think your folder structure is wrong. The following should be the structure as per your settings -

```
-static                            // MEDIA_ROOT and STATIC_ROOT setting
    -media                         // MEDIA_ROOT setting
-project(src)
    -app1
        -models.py
        -views.py
        -...
    -static                        // STATICFILES_DIRS setting
```

Comment: I replaced path with yours one but nothing changed. I had http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/media/photo/img.jpg in my browser and this is proper path to file but file for some reason doesn't save there.

Comment: Perhaps you are right but I guess my structure is also possible. What can I do in my case?

Comment: change the setting to MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static','media')

Comment: it will work but will be wrong, in the sense that you shouldn't store media files within the project src.

Comment: SOLVED! I simply remove empty string in MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '..', 'static','media') so it became MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static','media')

Comment: Thank you! you're right as for media should be out of project.